# How to install Polynote on Windows?

Tags: python, windows, scala, ipython, polynote

I've been searching around the Internet for a while but I have not been able to find detailed instructions on how to install [Polynote](https://polynote.org/) (The polyglot notebook
with first-class Scala support.) for Windows with mixing multiple languages, Python and Scala.

- [Github Link for Polynote](http://%20https://github.com/polynote/polynote).
- [Official Website](https://polynote.org/).

According to Official Website:

> Polynote is currently only tested on Linux and MacOS, using the Chrome browser as a client. We hope to be testing other platforms and browsers soon. Feel free to try it on your platform, and be sure to let us know about any issues you encounter by filing a bug report

I would really appreciate it if anyone here can share his/her method if he/she
had successfully installed Polynote on Windows, either from Virtual Machines
(VMware/Virtualbox) or directly.

Comment: A bit off-topic but have you tried installing it on the **WSL** instead?

Comment: WSL is a tool aimed at enabling users who need them to run Bash and core Linux command-line tools on Windows.

WSL does not aim to support GUI desktops or applications (e.g. Gnome, KDE, etc.)

Also, even though you will be able to run many popular server applications (e.g. Redis), we do not recommend WSL for server scenarios - https://askubuntu.com/questions/992399/what-are-the-limitations-of-the-windows-subsystem-for-linux

Comment: First yes you can, that is what I use at work and on my personal machine. You just need to emulate an XServer. Second, since the GUI, in this case, is chrome, you can just run the server on the WSL and open chrome on windows to access localhost. Finally, nothing on the question suggests that it will be exposed as an external server, but rather it seems like just as a development environment on a personal machine.

Answer (score 0):

You could install `Polynote` on Windows with `Ubuntu's subsystem for Windows`. To do that, you have to:

1. Enable Windows Developer mode:  Settings > Update & Security > For Developers > Developer Mode.
2. On `Windows Features` turn on [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://149366088.v2.pressablecdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/windows-bash-step-2.jpg).
3. Search for `Bash on Ubuntu on Windows` in your local search and you will find it.

Otherwise, you can skip the third step by installing `Ubuntu 18.0.4 LTS` from Window Store which is free and you can run linux commands there. You can actually install any `Linux` software and it works just as if it was native.

Having installed `Ubuntu for Windows`, you can just go through the steps on official documentation through the link which you provided us and you will be fine.

Comment: WSL is a tool aimed at enabling users who need them to run Bash and core Linux command-line tools on Windows.

WSL does not aim to support GUI desktops or applications (e.g. Gnome, KDE, etc.)

Also, even though you will be able to run many popular server applications (e.g. Redis), we do not recommend WSL for server scenarios - https://askubuntu.com/questions/992399/what-are-the-limitations-of-the-windows-subsystem-for-linux

Comment: Thank you, actually I did not know WSL referred to Windows Subsystem for Linux

Answer (score 0):

Might be a bit late but still maybe helpfull if you can't on WSL or if you easily want to keep polynote up-to-date.

I used docker to run polynote on Windows. Currently I'm reworking the Dockerfile I wrote to automatically update polynote on new releases. But as of now the script to run Polynote works for polynote version (0.3.11). https://github.com/moritzbaumotte/polynote-windows-inofficial

Here you only need docker-compose and docker installed. You can download the repository and execute the batch script. It will create a working docker image and run it, then you can access polynote on http://localhost:8192

The issue with the official docker images imo is the binding to 127.0.0.1 which needs to be 0.0.0.0, hence the config.yml in my repository.